# How we can get the unique values from a column in data dataframe with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[screenshot of the dataset-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qepAZ.png)
[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKaER.png)

```
(8,8),(4,3),(5,6),(7,6)

('6', '7'), ('7', '7'), ('7', '7'), ('7', '6'), ('6', '7')
```

I have this columns in my data set

What I want is to compare each element like 8,8 to other and get the unique from this column in separate column,

I am trying this code :

```
list1=content.Pairs
def unique(list1):
    unique_list = []
    for x in list1:
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
        for x in unique_list:
            print(x)
```

Expected Output is this :
(8,8)
(4,3)
(5,6)
(7,6)
(6,7)
(7,7) 
(7,7)

As below values are already there so its not going to be added and further matches are compared on this

Edit: edited

```
new_col = []
for e in conten.Pairs:
    new_col.append(list(dict.fromkeys(e)))
content['Unique'] = new_col
```

getting this from above code:

['(', '8', ',', ' ', ')'] ['(', '6', ',', ' ', '7', ')']

Expected Output is this : (8,8) (4,3) (5,6) (7,6) (6,7) (7,7)

As below values are already there so its not going to be added and further matches are compared on this

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all of your tuples (8,8), (4,3) etc. are in a single column in a pandas dataframe? Also are the tuples in the second row of your data really strings (surrounded by ' ' )?

Comment: embeded a image thats how my dataframe looks and i have to get the unique from pairs column to a separate column name unique

Comment: Please don't remove the important parts of your original question because they could be useful for others with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to get the unique pairs in your data:

```
import pandas as pd
# Create dummy dataset
original_1 = [8, 8,4 ,3 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,6 , 6]
original_2 = [e-1 for e in original_1]
list_of_tuples_1 = [(8,8),(4,3),(5,6),(7,6), (6,7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)]
list_of_tuples_2 = [(a-1, b-1) for (a,b) in list_of_tuples_1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'original': [original_1, original_2], 'tuples': [list_of_tuples_1, list_of_tuples_2]})

df
```

Out:

```
    original                    tuples
0   [8, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6] [(8, 8), (4, 3), (5, 6), (7, 6), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)]
1   [7, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5] [(7, 7), (3, 2), (4, 5), (6, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Iterate through each row and look for unique pairs, by converting to a dictionary, getting the unique keys, changing them back to a list and finally adding them to a new column in your dataframe:

```
new_col = []
for e in df.tuples:
    new_col.append(list(dict.fromkeys(e)))
df['Unique'] = new_col

df
```

Out:

```
    original                    tuples                                                                      Unique
0   [8, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6] [(8, 8), (4, 3), (5, 6), (7, 6), (6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)]    [(8, 8), (4, 3), (5, 6), (7, 6), (6, 7), (7, 7)]
1   [7, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5] [(7, 7), (3, 2), (4, 5), (6, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 5), (5, 6)]    [(7, 7), (3, 2), (4, 5), (6, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: Can you edit your original question and format the code, as it's impossible to read your comment..

Comment: I already edited the questions with your suggestion on it@jason

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed. Your variable called `content_tuples` isn't needed. In the for loop can you use for e in df.Pairs, where df is the name of your dataframe?

Comment: I tried with content.Pairs  but it give me same output i have shared in my question, its giving a single values and comma separted

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem, can you add a few rows of your data? You can use `df.iloc[:4, :]` to subset the first 4 rows of your `df`. And then `subset_df.to_clipboard()` to put the data in your clipboard so that you can paste the data into your question with `ctrl-v`, then I'll take a look.

Comment: i guess  there is something wrong with my column Values here

Comment: Screenshot of data  please check that image click on it you will see

Comment: I based the data I generated in my answer of what was in your screenshot. The code I wrote produces the result that you specified in your original question. So either you've copied the code incorrectly (the code you edited into your answer is not valid Python as there is a brace missing) or the data in your dataframe is different. It's not possible to help without seeing your data and your code.

Comment: please check the screenshot of the dataset-2 in my question description

Comment: Also copy and paste the code that you're actually running

Comment: new_col = []
for e in content.Pairs:
    new_col.append(list(dict.fromkeys(e)))
df['Unique'] = new_col

Comment: It seems like there are strings in your Pairs column, run `df.info()` and see which of your columns are listed as `object` or something numerical like `int`. If the column Pairs contains strings, convert them to integers on your originally dataframe or inside your for loop. E.g. `new_col.append(list(dict.fromkeys(int(e))))` (note the `int(e)`

Comment: content.Pairs.dtype is (object) and content.info show the data there is no info regarding object or int

Comment: You need to convert the column to integers, either use `int()` in the for loop as described in my previous comment OR `df.Pairs = df.Pairs.astype(int)`

Comment: i got error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)'
when converted to column values to content.Pairs = content.Pairs.astype(int)